# Recent Projects panel on VS2008 not working for fresh installs

Tags: visual-studio-2008

The Recent Projects panel on the Start Page of VS2008 Professional doesn't appear to work, and constantly remains empty.

I've noticed this on 3 of our developers VS2008 installations, in fact all the installations that weren't updated from 2005 but installed from scratch. I generally treat this as a bit of a curiosity, but now I have a new laptop and fresh install of VS2008, it's also happening to me, and I've upgraded the phenomena from a curio to an annoyance.

Anyone know if this is a bug or if there is a setting I'm missing somewhere.

Thanks

**EDIT** Thanks, but Tools | Options | Environment | General | "items shown in recently used lists" was and is set to 6 by default

Comment: Never had that before, but could you check if the list in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\ProjectMRUList is empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally worked it out!

The recent projects is driven by (or at least shares a 'Show' flag with) the Recent Documents in the Start Menu.

For some reason our SOE has this hidden.

Both the following need th be set to 0:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\NoRecentDocsHistory HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\NoRecentDocsMenu

Comment: I can only navigate to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies, there is no Explorer Sub folder after that. (windows 7)

Comment: @Entrodus I'm fairly sure I was using XP when I posted this answer. Feel free to update it for Win7 and above if you work out an answer

Answer (score 1):

Is Tools | Options | Environment | General | "items shown in recently used lists" set to a number greater than 0?